# Corda blob Inspector tool not available for download?

Tags: corda

I went through the documentation of blob-Inspector in v3.2 but the download 
[URL](https://www.corda.net/download.html) does not provide any jar for blob Inspector but only for DemoBench, is there a way to get this tool? Additionally, is node-explorer tool not available separately? it is only integrated in DemoBench, I went through its [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.2/node-explorer.html) where the steps are provided to build the jar using gradle but as soon as i click connect button after entering the credentials it stucks there and at the end i have to kill the process using task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blob Inspector can be downloaded from the [corda.net resources page](https://www.corda.net/develop/resources.html) or from the [Corda Artifactory](https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-blob-inspector/).

The Node Explorer can also be downloaded from the [Corda Artifactory](https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-tools-explorer/).

Comment: Thanks, got it and what about node explorer?

Comment: I've added a link to where the Node Explorer can be found.

Comment: https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-tools-blob-inspector